# [symfony][backbone] same templates for client and server side

Tags: symfony, backbone.js, seo

I am currently trying to do a webapp with backbone on the client side and symfony for the server side.
For the usual user, templates with underscore is enough for me but for seo, i would like a part of the website rendered identically with or without javascript.
I can have another identical template in twig but it seems for me to double the work and not really good coding practices.
Is there a way to reuse twig views and injects them as underscore template?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Twig.js](https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js) to reuse the server side twig files on frontend side.

Or you can use the php libraries for [Undescore](http://brianhaveri.github.io/Underscore.php) or [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php).